# Implementing gameloop in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, timer, game-loop

I am sorry for kind of often questions about this game but I don't know where and how to implement gameloop in my game. I would like the gameloop to work like that:

```
Settings();
if (startClicked == true)
{
    Spawn();
}
while (enemyKilled == true)
{
    Spawn();
}
```

Here's my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public int score1 = 0;
    public PictureBox enemy = new PictureBox();
    public PictureBox missile = new PictureBox();
    public int enemyX;
    public int enemyY;
    public int missileX;
    public int missileY;
    public bool enemyKilled;
    public bool startClicked;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        logo.Visible = false;
        startbutton.Visible = false;
        spaceship.Visible = false;
        score.Visible = false;
        labelEnemyX.Visible = false;
        labelEnemyY.Visible = false;
        labelMissileX.Visible = false;
        labelMissileY.Visible = false;

    }

    private void Settings()
    {
        logo.Visible = true;
        startbutton.Visible = true;
        score.Text = Convert.ToString(score1);
    }

    private void Spawn()
    {
        enemy.Visible = true;
        missile.Visible = true;
        System.Timers.Timer enemyMove = new System.Timers.Timer();
        enemyMove.Interval = 100;
        Random enemyPosition = new Random();
        int enemyX = enemyPosition.Next(30, 400);
        int enemyY = enemy.Location.Y;
        enemy.Location = new Point(enemyX, 0);
        enemy.Image = WindowsFormsApplication16.Properties.Resources.Enemy2;
        enemy.Width = 36;
        enemy.Height = 29;
        this.Controls.Add(enemy);
        enemyMove.Elapsed += (sender, args) =>
            {
                enemy.Location = new Point(enemyX, enemy.Location.Y + 2);
                enemyX = enemy.Location.X;
                enemyY = enemy.Location.Y;
                labelEnemyX.Text = Convert.ToString(enemyX);
                labelEnemyY.Text = Convert.ToString(enemyY);
                if (enemyY <= -10)
                {
                    enemyKilled = false;
                }
            }; enemyMove.Start();
    }

    private void AddScore()
    {
        if (enemyKilled == true)
        {
            score1++;
            score.Text = Convert.ToString(score1);
        }
    }

    private void MissileMove()
    {
        System.Timers.Timer missileMove = new System.Timers.Timer();
        missileMove.Interval = 30;
        missileMove.Elapsed += (sender, args) =>
            {
                if (missile.Location.Y >= -30)
                {
                    missile.Location = new Point(missile.Location.X, missile.Location.Y - 15);
                    missileX = missile.Location.X;
                    missileY = missile.Location.Y;
                    labelMissileX.Text = Convert.ToString(missileX);
                    labelMissileY.Text = Convert.ToString(missileY);
                    int enemyToMissileLocationX = Convert.ToInt32(labelEnemyX.Text);
                    int enemyToMissileLocationY = Convert.ToInt32(labelEnemyY.Text);
                    if ((missileX - enemyToMissileLocationX <= 20 && missileY - enemyToMissileLocationY <= 20 && missileX - enemyToMissileLocationX >= 0 && missileY - enemyToMissileLocationY >= 0) || (enemyToMissileLocationX - missileX <= 20 && enemyToMissileLocationY - missileY <= 20 && enemyToMissileLocationX - missileX >= 0 && enemyToMissileLocationY - missileY >= 0))
                    {
                        missile.Visible = false;
                        enemy.Visible = false;
                        enemyKilled = true;
                    }
                }
            }; missileMove.Start();

    }

    void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Settings();
        if (startClicked == true)
        {
            Spawn();
        }
        while (enemyKilled == true)
        {
            Spawn();
        }
    }

    private void startbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.startClicked = true;
        logo.Visible = false;
        startbutton.Visible = false;
        spaceship.Visible = true;
        score.Visible = true;
        startbutton.Enabled = false;

    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
        {
            if (spaceship.Location.X <= 370)
            {
                spaceship.Location = new Point(spaceship.Location.X + 10, spaceship.Location.Y);
            }
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
        {
            if (spaceship.Location.X >= 0)
            {
                spaceship.Location = new Point(spaceship.Location.X - 10, spaceship.Location.Y);
            }
        }
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
        {
            missile.Image = WindowsFormsApplication16.Properties.Resources.Missile;
            missile.Height = 42;
            missile.Width = 12;
            missile.Location = new Point(spaceship.Location.X + 28, spaceship.Location.Y + 15);
            this.Controls.Add(missile);
            MissileMove();

        }
    }
}
```

Update:

```
    private void MissileMove()
    {
        System.Timers.Timer missileMove = new System.Timers.Timer();
        missileMove.Interval = 30;
        missileMove.Elapsed += (sender, args) =>
            {
                if (missile.Location.Y >= -30)
                {
                    missile.Location = new Point(missile.Location.X, missile.Location.Y - 15);
                    missileX = missile.Location.X;
                    missileY = missile.Location.Y;
                    labelMissileX.Text = Convert.ToString(missileX);
                    labelMissileY.Text = Convert.ToString(missileY);
                    int enemyToMissileLocationX = Convert.ToInt32(labelEnemyX.Text);
                    int enemyToMissileLocationY = Convert.ToInt32(labelEnemyY.Text);
                    if ((missileX - enemyToMissileLocationX <= 20 && missileY - enemyToMissileLocationY <= 20 && missileX - enemyToMissileLocationX >= 0 && missileY - enemyToMissileLocationY >= 0) || (enemyToMissileLocationX - missileX <= 20 && enemyToMissileLocationY - missileY <= 20 && enemyToMissileLocationX - missileX >= 0 && enemyToMissileLocationY - missileY >= 0))
                    {
                        missile.Visible = false;
                        enemy.Visible = false;
                        enemyKilled = true;
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                        Application.DoEvents();
                        Spawn();
                    }
                }
            }; missileMove.Start();
```

Tried to do this with the class and yes, it spawn enemies once more but the animation is bugged and I can see enemies jumping from one position to another position.
Thank you for help.

Comment: Please add your questin with more detail

Comment: I'd like the game to spawn the enemy everytime I kill the enemy.

Comment: It is a massive long code, nobody will read it as a think.
Please update your question, for more answer. Clean the unneccery code or method body

Comment: I added the whole code but the problem is where to implement the first part which is gameloop, where in Windows Forms.

Comment: A game loop requires a drastically different way to program the code.  You'd have to throw everything away and start from scratch.  Which is okay, version 0.2 is fairly inevitable.

Comment: What problem(s) are you experiencing with the game loop in Form_Load as you currently have coded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a Windows form.  As such, I would suggest that you have a background thread that runs in a while loop and handles all of the movement/update logic of your game.  The complex part will be managing state between the Windows form thread, and the game thread.  You will need to ensure you're event handlers for button clicks etc. that update game state are doing so in a thread safe manner, as they will be on the GUI thread.  The game loop thread will need to update state on the GUI, which will require what is known as marshelling, because only the GUI thread is allowed to access controls that exist on the form like buttons, etc.

The topics of thread management, thread safety, and marshelling I'll leave to you to research.

This assumes it's some sort of real time game, rather than turn based.  If it is turn based, then you don't really need a game loop.  You could accomplish the same goal by using a state diagram and purely event driven design.

Comment: No need to introduce all the complexity of multi-threading just for a game loop is there? So long as the loop includes `Application.DoEvents()` and runs at a reasonable frame rate (so DoEvents occurs frequently), everything should run easily on a single thread. That's how the games created by Scrolling Game Development Kit 2 (http://sgdk2.sf.net/) operate.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN There certainly isn't a "need" to do as I've suggested.  However, an architecture that relies on DoEvents is sometimes considered bad practice because it makes the responsiveness of the UI dependent on every piece of code between each DoEVents call to be **guaranteed** to be fast.  That being said, I would encourage you to post your suggestion as an answer, as I feel it is equally valid given the tradeoffs.  It would indeed be significantly simpler to implement.

Comment: I tried to do this but the problem is that it's spawning more enemies jumping from one enemy to another enemy. I added third part of code with it.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to implement the game loop as you have in a function like `Form_Load` (or the `main` function if you are familiar with integrating that into a Windows Forms application), but add calls to `Application.DoEvents` inside the loop to make sure the window is still responsive to events like moving and sizing and button clicking. Other than that, you might have to clarify what problems you are experiencing with your current solution in order to get a more complete and detailed answer.